# Запретить AJAX запросы для не авторизованных пользователей

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Хочу что бы при вызове какого либо аякс события проверялось залогинен ли пользователь и если нет запретить отроботку аякса. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По верхнему ответу, ничего создавать в сессиях не надо, в ядре есть функция [is_user_logged_in();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)
А вообще надо пользовать API движка, без велосипедов
Если использовать встроенное  в ядро API ajax то достаточно  использовать экшен 
`add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );`
без акшена
`add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_%28action%29

и ajax для не авторизованных юзерей работать не будет

Answer (score 3):

Допустим создать в сессии переменную, которая отвечает за статус авторизации

```
$_SESSION['is_auth'] = true;
```

Дальше можно написать что-нить вида

```
function sendAjax () {
    <? if(!$_SESSION['is_auth']) echo 'return'; ?>
    /* а тут ваш код */
}
```

Но в плане безопасности эт не круто, лучше вообще проверять авторизацию на стороне сервера и от результата выдавать нужный контент ( с ajax обработчиками или без )

Еще как вариант, вынести все функции для авторизованных в отдельный файл, подгружать его, если мы авторизованы, не подгружать, если разлогинились.